# Can I keep "pushing to Origin" everyday with GitDesktop?

Tags: github

I'm not sure if it's an appropriate question here, and I haven't found another related question.

I'm new to programming, and I save my work every day, updating my repository with GItHub Desktop.

Is OK to do that? Is this good practice?

Is there a better way to keep saving my work on a daily basis?

Comment: Don't use git around your work day. Use it around the features you develop. Commit each time you have a subset of a feature completed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @bolov thanks you for your time.. you comment with contribution of Rokas was all I needed to know. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it’s perfectly fine to push your project to origin and that is one of the reasons for git as it keeps your work safe. Further, having frequent commits during stages allows you revert back to those commits when you make a mistake or something goes wrong.

Although when it comes to best practice you should create different branches in your GitHub project and merge those branches into the main branch once it is in a complete state so your main branch is always a functioning product. Here’s some further reading on this:

https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-branches

You may also want to explore more of the GitHub docs.

Git can become quiet complex especially when working with other people so it’s useful to get in the habit with following branching structures and writing useful commit messages. Also you’ll often find different organisations have specific rules to this and you’ll have to understand git enough to work with in the way your team does.

Comment: Awesome...Thank you very much, that was exactly what I needed to know, now I'm going to work properly ejhehe...